# Как вывести результат в самой консоли, а не в Clion

Tags: windows, консоль, clion

Здравствуйте. Можно ли выводить результат в консоли Винды, а не в IDE Clion?

Comment: shift+F9 запускает отладку с отдельным окном

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan может оформить ответом и повысить процент отвеченных вопросов на руСО? :)

Comment: @alexolut не против

Comment: от чистого сердца, помогу вам повысить процент отвеченых вопросов

Answer (score -2):

Shift+F9 запускает отладку в "debug режиме" с отдельным окном.